# Insecure font blocking my https website

Tags: ssl, fonts, https

Dear stackoverflow experts,

I've been reading in stackoverflow forum about the issue but didn't find a solution

I'm experiencing a problem with my website https://baliradar.com
since I installed SSL. I changed all the http links by https.

However I cannot resolve the problem of insecure font though, here's the console log error message:

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://baliradar.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/nj47mAZe0mYUIySgfn0wpQ.ttf'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I have been searching for hours with FileZilla in the files of my theme "winning agent pro" and in other directories of my website but I never found the html code for the font. I tried to search for specific keywords ("fonts", "gstatic") in my File Manager from my CPanel but there's no records found.

I also tried to use the "Developer Tool" of Chrome to find the source of the font without success.

I'm clueless here and was wondering if someone has an idea or a solution?

Thank you for your time.

Xavier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several `http://` links in your CSS code, which is linked in your header as `<link
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://baliradar.com/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/e4a39/default.include.08bf2a.css" media="all" />`:

```
.mCSB_buttonRight{background-position:-80px -56px}@font-face{font-family:'Lato';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/nj47mAZe0mYUIySgfn0wpQ.ttf) format('truetype')}@font-face{font-family:'Lato';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/v0SdcGFAl2aezM9Vq_aFTQ.ttf) format('truetype')}@font-face{font-family:'Lato';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/DvlFBScY1r-FMtZSYIYoYw.ttf) format('truetype')}@font-face{font-family:'Lato';font-style:normal;font-weight:900;src:local('Lato Black'), local('Lato-Black'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/4cKlrioa77J2iqTqBgkRWg.ttf) format('truetype')}.currencyr{position:fixed;z-index:2147483647}.currencyr .currencyr-container,
```

As it seems that this is a minified version of your css, search in your current theme's css-files for the `http` phrase. You can do so using grep for example:

```
grep 'http://fonts' * -R
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this issue was caused by my caching plugin (W3 Total Cache). Disabling it solved the issue but you may want to keep the plugin and change the font URLs in the CSS file from HTTP to HTTPS.

> I came across this issue when the Social Pug plugin stopped showing
> icons on the social media buttons. The root cause was the caching
> enabled by W3 Total Cache plugin. If you are in a similar situation,
> there are three ways to fix the issue:
>
> - Disable W3 Total Cache (not recommended because your website’s performance may decrease)
> - Change the font URLs of Social Pug plugin to HTTPS
> - In some cases, URL Rewrite rules may cause this issue. Check your .htaccess file

[Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font](https://port135.com/2019/03/04/mixed-content-insecure-font/)